# Can I include a check for null details inside a forEach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this code:

```
         foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (result.definition != null)
                {
                    WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
                        .Where(w => w.Definition == result.definition)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (wordForm == null)
                    {
                        wordForm = addWordForm(result, word);
                    }

                    addWordFormExamples(result, word, wordForm);
                    addWordFormSynonyms(result, word, wordForm);

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
```

Is there a way I could optimize this using a .forEach and also by adding in a check to see if the definition is null as part of the actual .forEach ? I would like to clean up this code and so trying what I can to further simplify it.

Note that I already moved this to a private method:

```
    private void processWordForm(Word word, Result result)
    {
        WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
                                    .Where(w => w.Definition == result.definition)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

        if (wordForm == null)
        {
            wordForm = addWordForm(result, word);
        }

        addWordFormExamples(result, word, wordForm);
        addWordFormSynonyms(result, word, wordForm);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So now I just need a more tidy way to call this method if there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting all the results before doing the `foreach` loop and inside the loop you check if **every single one** contains a definition which is not null.That means that you are actually only interested in results which contain a definition.

You can re-factor your code slightly by modifying the query which sets the `results` object to only contain results with a definition.This will remove the need for having the `null` check inside the `foreach` loop.

**Something like this:**

```
var results = sourceOfData.Where(i => e.definition != null).ToList();

foreach (var result in results)
{
        WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
            .Where(w => w.Definition == result.definition)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (wordForm == null)
        {
            wordForm = addWordForm(result, word);
        }

        addWordFormExamples(result, word, wordForm);
        addWordFormSynonyms(result, word, wordForm);

        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: When asking about optimizing the code, I don't think using the Where-method is going to do this for you. It, in itself, uses loop(s) to filter out the things it doesn't need, resulting in a slower execution of this code in comparison to the code in the question. Where is the optimizing?

Comment: LINQ to Objects performs a linear traversal. LINQ to Entities translates the code into a SQL WHERE.She has db.SaveChanges() inside her question so I assume she's doing LINQ to Entities so my answer should in fact optimize the code.But even if it didn't it's still looks neater by removing the null check and let LINQ handle that for you, the code looks much more readable.